# how to extract specific word from string using regex in python

Tags: python, regex, string, text-extraction

I have two string contain word with their type's:

```
text1 = 'Mau/VBT ngasih/NN hadiah/NN untuk/IN Anniv/NN ,/, Graduation/NN ,/, Birthday/NN ,/, Wedding/NN ,/, dll/VBT ?/. Nih/DT ,/, ada/VBI hadiah/NN kece/JJ yang/SC at/IN Yasmin/NNP 33/CDP'
text2 = 'Yang/SC kelaparan/NN habis/VBI latihan/NN ilovenaylambem/NN at/IN Jl/NNP Halimun/NNP Raya/NNP ,/, Menteng/NN'
```

I like to extract any word form word with `/NN` tag to word with `/NNP` and `/CDP` tag. Here is my code so far (still only work with `/NNP` tag):

```
import re

def entityExtractPreposition(text):
    text = re.findall(r'([^\s/]*/IN\b[^/]*(?:/(?!IN\b)[^/]*)*/NNP\b)', text)
    return text

text1 = 'Mau/VBT ngasih/NN hadiah/NN untuk/IN Anniv/NN ,/, Graduation/NN ,/, Birthday/NN ,/, Wedding/NN ,/, dll/VBT ?/. Nih/DT ,/, ada/VBI hadiah/NN kece/JJ yang/SC at/IN Yasmin/NNP 33/CDP'
prepo1 = entityExtractPreposition(text1)

text2 = 'Yang/SC kelaparan/NN habis/VBI latihan/NN ilovenaylambem/NN at/IN Jl/NNP Halimun/NNP Raya/NNP ,/, Menteng/NN'
prepo2 = entityExtractPreposition(text2)

print text1
print prepo1
print ''
print text2
print prepo2
```

The result of the code so far:

```
Mau/VBT ngasih/NN hadiah/NN untuk/IN Anniv/NN ,/, Graduation/NN ,/, Birthday/NN ,/, Wedding/NN ,/, dll/VBT ?/. Nih/DT ,/, ada/VBI hadiah/NN kece/JJ yang/SC at/IN Yasmin/NNP 33/CDP
['at/IN Yasmin/NNP']

Yang/SC kelaparan/NN habis/VBI latihan/NN ilovenaylambem/NN at/IN Jl/NNP Halimun/NNP Raya/NNP ,/, Menteng/NN
['at/IN Jl/NNP Halimun/NNP Raya/NNP']
```

As we see for the first string (`text1`) the `entityExtractPreposition` still fail to get `33/CDP`. How to make the `entityExtractPreposition` work fine either with `/CDP` tag in text1 or `/NNP` in text2?

The expected result is:

```
Mau/VBT ngasih/NN hadiah/NN untuk/IN Anniv/NN ,/, Graduation/NN ,/, Birthday/NN ,/, Wedding/NN ,/, dll/VBT ?/. Nih/DT ,/, ada/VBI hadiah/NN kece/JJ yang/SC at/IN Yasmin/NNP 33/CDP
['at/IN Yasmin/NNP 33/CDP']

Yang/SC kelaparan/NN habis/VBI latihan/NN ilovenaylambem/NN at/IN Jl/NNP Halimun/NNP Raya/NNP ,/, Menteng/NN
['at/IN Jl/NNP Halimun/NNP Raya/NNP']
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\b[^\s/]+/IN\b(?:(?!/IN\b).)*/(?:NNP|CDP)\b
```